# Why I am unable to login to Stack Overflow with my Yahoo OpenID?

Tags: support, login

For past few weeks I haven't been able login to Stack Overflow with my Yahoo ID.

When I click on the Yahoo logo to log in I get this error:

> Error 111 (net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.